# Service class inheritance and files order

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have service (class in TypeScript) `app/resources/GeneralResource.ts` and other services in the folder `app/resources/`.  I want to inherit all my resources from `GeneralResources`.

All files (classes) that are going after `GeneralResource.ts` file alphabetically are working fine.  But all files (classes) that are going before `GeneralResource.ts` have a execution-time error.

Here is an example class:

```
export class DefectReasonResource extends GeneralResource implements IDefectReasonResource {

    static $inject = ['$q', '$http', 'baseUrl'];

    constructor(public $q:ng.IQService, public $http:ng.IHttpService, public baseUrl:string) {
       super($q, $http);
    }

    // ...
```

This class compile fine:

```
var app;
(function (app) {
    var common;
    (function (common) {
        var DefectReasonResource = (function (_super) {
            __extends(DefectReasonResource, _super);
            function DefectReasonResource($q, $http, baseUrl) {
                _super.call(this, $q, $http);
                this.$q = $q;
                this.$http = $http;
                this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
            }
            DefectReasonResource.$inject = ['$q', '$http', 'baseUrl'];
            return DefectReasonResource;
        })(common.GeneralResource);
        common.DefectReasonResource = DefectReasonResource;
        angular.module('myApp').service('defectReasonResource', DefectReasonResource);
    })(common = app.common || (app.common = {}));
})(app || (app = {}));
```

But when I open the file I have an error in the browser:

> > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

I just want to underline that I don't have this problem with all classes that are declared after `GeneralResource`.

I think it will be better to remove inheritance and inject `GeneralResource` to all my services. But I am wondering it is possible to fix inheritance solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not elaborate how your setup looks like. But I encountered this when I used (TypeScript) internal modules. You just have to make sure that you don't forget to add reference comment:

```
///<reference path="relative/path/to/GeneralResource.ts" />
```

in your `app/resources/serviceName.ts` files. The purpose of the comment is to make sure that the order of files (or their contents) is correct in the final `app.js` file (if you use `--outFile` flag).